# wagmi useSendTransaction doesnt work with wallet connect(trust wallet)

Tags: ethers.js, react, walletconnect, wagmi, trustwallet

I'm trying to send eth from one wallet to another using wagmi + ether js, everything works in the browser through the metamask, but the transaction confirmation does not appear through wallet connect, and in the trust wallet application it says "method is not supported" has anyone come across this problem and how to solve it? I've been trying to solve this for 4 days now.

[image: trust wallet error]

[image: log error]

```
const SendTransaction = () => {

  const { config } = usePrepareSendTransaction({
    request: { to: "moxey.eth", value: utils.parseEther("0.0001") },
  });
  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, sendTransaction, error } =
    useSendTransaction(config);

  console.log("err", error);

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!sendTransaction} onClick={() => sendTransaction?.()}>
        Send Transaction
      </button>
      {isLoading && <div>Check Wallet</div>}
      {isSuccess && <div>Transaction: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: [https://github.com/wagmi-dev/wagmi/issues/1642](https://github.com/wagmi-dev/wagmi/issues/1642) you can check here I have same issue. I can't get hash only via trust wallet

Answer (score 0):

```
import {formatUnits} from 'viems';

const SendTransaction = () => {
// try to replace config with request
  const { request} = usePrepareSendTransaction({
    to: "moxey.eth", 
    value: formatUnits("0.0001",18), //use formatUnits from viems, ethers is not supported anymore
  });
  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, sendTransaction, error } =
    useSendTransaction(request);

  console.log("err", error);

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!sendTransaction} onClick={() => sendTransaction()}>
        Send Transaction
      </button>
      {isLoading && <div>Check Wallet</div>}
      {isSuccess && <div>Transaction: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

try this one...

Answer (score 0):

add **data:"0x"** to your request.

```js
const { config } = usePrepareSendTransaction(
  {
    request: { 
    to: "moxey.eth", 
    value: utils.parseEther("0.0001") 
  },
  data:"0x"
});
```